# Determine table to select from based on indicator

Tags: oracle

I have a situation where there are three tables with same table design (same amount of columns, same PK, same FK) but store different value on one date, only one data will be stored per day in each table. Each table has a flag column (Y or N) to determine which should be the value to be reported on the specific day. Only one table's value will be flagged as Y for one CODE in one day.

Example:

```
Table 1:

Date | Code | Value | Flag 
01-DEC, ABC,  111, N

Table 2:

Date | Code | Value | Flag 
01-DEC, ABC,  222, N

Table 3:

Date | Code | Value | Flag 
01-DEC, ABC,  333, Y
```

Refer to the example above, the value of CODE ABC for date: 01-DEC should be 333 as it's flagged as Y.

How should the SQL look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would strongly question the data model that has three identical tables that seem to store essentially the same information and serve the same purpose.

You could, assuming that there will be only one `Y` row, do

```
SELECT *
  FROM( SELECT *
          FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT *
          FROM table2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT *
          FROM table3 )
 WHERE flag = 'Y'
```

Comment: Thank you, in fact i have simplify the question, the three tables are designed based on client's business requirements.

Comment: @edx - The data model still seems highly suspect.  If you have to `UNION ALL` multiple tables together to get a result and those tables have the same sort of data, that strongly implies that you really want one table.

Comment: Thank for your advice Justin, will reconsider that :)